# How do I create UserControl in IronPython WPF project?

Tags: wpf, user-controls, ironpython

Iron Python Tools Visual Studio 2010 does not provide a way to add WPF User Control in a IronPython WPF project? How do I make one? I tried copy-pasting User Control from C# WPF project but it did not work. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be quite the same as what you're asking, but I wanted to make a `UserControl` the content of a `TabItem`, to keep the XAML for the tabs in separate files.

I haven't found a clean way in IronPython, but I have found a reasonable hack. I imagine it would work for components other than `TabItem`s, too.

First, I named my `TabItem`, like this:

```
<TabItem Name="my_tab_item" Header="My Tab Item" />
```

Then I loaded my `UserControl`'s XAML into a custom class:

```
import wpf
import clr
clr.AddReference("System.Xml")
from System.Windows.Controls import UserControl

class MyUserControl(UserControl):
    def __init__(self):
        wpf.LoadComponent(self, 'my_user_control.xaml')
```

And I added it to the `TabItem` like this:

```
self.FindName("my_tab_item").Content = MyUserControl()
```